# Building User Flow using Html5 Canvas, JavaScript and React.

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, diagram, react-canvas

I want to develop, user flow diagram library using Html5 Canvas, Js and React. Can anyone guide me on this, please?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's too late for answering this question, but i will try to do it anyways..

First off, in order to accomplish this you will need to learn a lot about Javascript, the Canvas element, a little bit of mathematics and of course ReactJS.

I suggest you to begin with this amazing [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial) offered by MDN, is very clear and goes deep into the details of this subject.

As you can see the table of contents is the following:

1. Basic usage
2. Drawing shapes
3. Applying styles and colors
4. Drawing text
5. Using images
6. Transformations
7. Compositing and clipping
8. Basic animations
9. Advanced animations
10. Pixel manipulation
11. Hit regions and accessibility
12. Optimizing the canvas
13. Finale

When you finish this, you'll be able to begin the development of your project. The more easiest way to approach this will be to use a library made for this, like GoJS, mx-graph, bpmn-js or else. But if you want the fully customization and flexibility beyond the hard-work, making your own implementations and development is the way.